# ' vs " " vs ' ' ' in Groovy .When to Use What?

Tags: groovy, operators

I am getting really confused in Groovy. When to use what for `Strings` in Groovy ?

1)  Single Quotes - `' '` 
  2)  Double Quotes - `" "` 
  3)  Triple Quotes - `'''`

My code:

```
 println("Tilak Rox")
 println('Tilak Rox')
 println('''Tilak Rox''')
```

All tend to produce same results.
**When to Use What ?**

Comment: Java tag removed.  This isn't a Java question

Comment: @tim_yates peace ✌️

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would confuse you even more, saying, that you can also use slash `/`, dolar-slash `$/` and triple-double quotes `"""` with same result. =)

So, what's the difference:

1. **Single vs Double quote**: Most important difference. Single-quoted is ordinary Java-like string. Double-quoted is a `GString`, and it allows *string-interpolation*. I.e. you can have expressions embedded in it: `println("${40 + 5}")` prints 45, while `println('${ 40 + 5}')` will produce `${ 40 + 5}`. This expression can be pretty complex, can reference variables or call methods.
2. **Triple quote** and **triple double-quote** is the way to make string *multiline*. You can open it on one line in your code, copy-paste big piece of xml, poem or sql expression in it and don't bother yourself with string concatenation.
3. **Slashy** `/` and **dollar-slashy** `$/` strings are here to help with regular expressions. They have special escape rules for '\' and '/' respectfully.

As @tim pointed, there is a good [official documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings) for that, explaining small differences in escaping rules and containing examples as well.

Most probably you don't need to use multiline/slashy strings very often, as you use them in a very particular scenarios. But when you do they make a huge difference in readability of your code!

Answer (score 6):

Single quotes `'` are for basic Strings

Double quotes `"` are for templated Strings ie:

```
def a = 'tim'
assert "Hi $a" == 'Hi tim'
```

Triple single quotes `'''` are for multi-line basic Strings

Triple double `"""` quotes are for multi-line templated strings

There's also slashy strings `/hello $a/` which are templated

And dollar slashy Strings `$/hello $a/$` which are multi-line and templated

[They're all documented quite well in the documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings)