# How to mount Jenkins workspace in docker container using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins in docker. The `/var/jenkins_home` is mounted on `/var/jenkins-data` on my host. My Jenkins can execute docker commands (mount of sockets) and I've installed the git plugin and pipeline plugin.

Now I have a pipeline job named `test` and the following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Clone') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/lvthillo/maven-hello-world.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Build in Docker') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3.5.2'
                    args '-v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test:/opt/maven -w /opt/maven'
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'mvn -v'
                sh 'mvn clean install'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is cloning my public repo from github. This works. In the next step I want to start a docker container (maven) and print the current directory, the maven version and perform a clean install.

The output of the 3 commands is:

```
[test@2] Running shell script
+ pwd
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test@2
[Pipeline] sh
[test@2] Running shell script
+ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T07:58:13Z)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.86-boot2docker", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[Pipeline] sh
[test@2] Running shell script
+ mvn clean install

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.179 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-12T12:12:00Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/31M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test@2). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

It seems to work because maven is not installed on my host, so it's executed from inside the container, but it's suddenly creating a new workspace (`@2`) instead of using the existing one from where I cloned the repo. I don't want to clone the repo in my container immediately because I want multiple stages, all with different containers, but all executed on my git repo in my workspace.

What am I doing wrong or how can I fix this?
I was thinking it was maybe because of the agent step. my first step can run on any agent (any slave), the docker step will run in the docker container, but must of course run on that same slave als where the `git clone` was executed.

Answer (score 18):

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Clone') {
        steps {
            git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/lvthillo/maven-hello-world.git'
            stash name:'scm', includes:'*'
        }
    }

    stage('Build in Docker') {
        steps {
            unstash 'scm'
            script{
                docker.image('maven:3.5.2').inside{ 
                    sh 'pwd'
                    sh 'mvn -v'
                    sh 'mvn clean install'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can use this pipeline even with a multi-node setup. Docker plugin mounts your workspace as a docker workspace too.Hence, it is not necessary to mount any volume unless they are outside the workspace.

Comment: The only docker plugin that I know of that uses the `docker.image(...){...}` syntax is the `Docker Pipeline` plugin ( https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/ ), maintained by `carroll`.  Is this the `Docker plugin by cloudbees` you're referring to?  If not, which plugin are you referring to?

Answer (score 17):

Thanks, the Previous solution works for me. My version for node container and ${PWD} as param

```
stage('Build Solution') { 
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'node:6-alpine'
                args '-v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app'
                reuseNode true
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
```

Comment: For anyone like me who used that and it didn't work (`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PWD for class: groovy.lang.Binding`), make sure you're using single quotes, otherwise Jenkins treats it like a templatable `GString` ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37465198

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Jenkins 2.319.3 since it seems to put `args` in between its default `-u` and `-w`. What a pain.

Answer (score 7):

My last explanation was helping myself to solve the problem:
This [text](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Controlling-your-build-environment) helped me to solve it. I had to ensure that all the steps on my pipeline were using the same agent as the initial one where I performed my git clone:

Addit `reuseNode` true solved it:

```
stage('Build in Docker') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3.5.2'
                    args '-v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test:/opt/maven -w /opt/maven'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
```

Comment: And how would you specify args value for workspace that always changes on every build? Can I just do args '-v ${PWD}' ?

Comment: @Angelina you can just use ${workspace} in Jenkins which will resolve it automatically.

Comment: I tried so many things... Are you saying add it to args? docker{args ${workspace}}

Answer (score 0):

The error message returned by maven indicates that was not able to find the pom.xml file in the directory where the execution was launched.

I had the same issue, and solved by cd to the directory containing my project pom.xml.