# jenkins docker agent and workspaces

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Using multibranch pipelines and running a docker agent in one of my stages I found the workspace inside the container is not being updated:

```
stage('run inside container') {
     agent {
         docker {
             image "my/image"}}
    steps{
       sh 'ls -l'
       ...
```

So I found jenkins is running this docker command:

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -u root -w /home/jenkins/workspace/myworkspace@2
```

its mounting the workspace but with a "2". This is not the main workspace and it looks like its not being updated. How can I have it use my main workspace?

Comment: I think this question/answers can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226183/how-to-mount-jenkins-workspace-in-docker-container-using-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to run a stage inside another container, then instead of using agents, simply do this:

```
stage("NPM Install") {
            steps {
                script {
                    // this will  generate node_modules folder and map it 
                    // back to this workspace.
                    docker.image("node:12.14.1-alpine").inside {

                        sh "npm install"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This way Jenkins will bind mount the current pipeline workspace with the container.

Answer (score 3):

Use `reuseNode true` in docker agent options.

```
stage('run inside container') {
     agent {
         docker {
             image "my/image"
             reuseNode true
         }
    }
    steps{
       sh 'ls -l'
       ...
```

See `Workspace synchronization` [in the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins create new workspace for user with myworkspace@2 or @3 if more than one build is triggered parallelly. This is to make sure that two jobs should not overwrite with each other.

If your requirement is to run only one job at a time you can enable "Do not allow concurrent builds" as shown in image below for you job.

[image]