# Where is $HOME directory in running docker image on Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to prepare my own Jenkins Pipeline, for now I have stage like this

```
stage('Test stage'){
    steps{
            sh "docker run --name test_container test:image"
            script {
                docker.image('test:image').inside {
                    sh 'some_ansible_script'
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My ansible script needs to be run in $HOME directory, normally I run my image with -it parameters and I can go to $HOME, but in this case pwd show me my jenkins $HOME directory. Where I can find my image $HOME directory on Jenkins?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I think I'm facing a similar scenario with Elixir's .mix folder

Comment: Well, in the meantime I change my approach, I run docker images as agent in Dockerfile where I mount workspace to container. Checkout this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226183/how-to-mount-jenkins-workspace-in-docker-container-using-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new stage before this one and run `echo ${HOME}` in it. The output is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

We can add this before the steps to set the HOME.

```
  environment {
    HOME = '/my/custom/path'
  }
  steps {
           .....
```