# Jenkins variable not expanding, why?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm setting up a stage in a Jenkins pipeline script.

I wanted to create artifacts with build numbers in the name so I setup the following command:

```
bat '7z a -tzip staging_${BUILD_NUMBER} @JenkinsStagingFiles.txt'
archiveArtifacts 'staging_${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip'
```

The bat command doesn't expand ${BUILD_NUMBER} and leaves it alone, whereas the archiveArtifacts command does. How do I get the bat command to expand ${BUILD_NUMBER}?

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. I do the exact same thing in my JenkinsFile and it works just fine. Are you sure it doesn't expand that variable? There must be something else going on here can you add more of your Groovy?

Comment: What happens if you add `print "7z a -tzip staging_${BUILD_NUMBER} @JenkinsStagingFiles.txt"`

Comment: It looks as though print doesn't expand either: [Pipeline] echo
7z a -tzip staging_${BUILD_NUMBER} @JenkinsStagingFiles.txt

Comment: Ahah! The difference is between single quotes and double qoutes! Single quotes doesn't expand, double quotes does!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37465198/4279361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use " on the bat line and ' on the archiveArtifacts line

```
bat "7z a -tzip staging_${BUILD_NUMBER} @JenkinsStagingFiles.txt"
archiveArtifacts 'staging_${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip'
```

Comment: You could use double-quotes in the second line as well. This is a Groovy feature: variables are expanded in double-quoted strings but not in single quoted ones.

Comment: Expansion also doesn't take place in ''' (triple single quote) blocks.