# Shell command not working from jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Below doesn't work. Please let me know what the issue is.

`sh label: 'Salesforce Validation  on ' + salesforceEnvironment,` 
 `script: 'sfdx force:source:deploy --verbose' + checkOnlyParam + ' --wait 1440 --manifest manifest/package.xml --targetusername ' + salesforceEnvironment > SalesForceValidation.log`

Comment: Could add more detail , for example error displayed during the job execution.

Comment: In case you'd like to have the `sh` script's `stdout` (and `stderr` and `status`) passed back to your pipeline script see [How to return stdout and stderr together with the status from a Jenkins Pipeline sh script step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68967642/1744774).

Answer (score 2):

Use `${...}` for [string interpolation inside a GString](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation):

```groovy
sh  label: "Salesforce Validation on ${salesforceEnvironment}",
    script: """
        sfdx force:source:deploy
        --verbose ${checkOnlyParam}
        --wait 1440
        --manifest manifest/package.xml
        --targetusername ${salesforceEnvironment} > SalesForceValidation.log
        """
```

Comment: Reference: [Groovy Syntax, String interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) ... Mei, a Steirer! Griaß di! :)

Comment: (on groovy) Using triple-double-quote may improve readability : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464887/vs-vs-in-groovy-when-to-use-what

Answer (score 0):

Below worked

tee('SalesForceValidation.log') {
sh label: 'Salesforce Validation  on ' + salesforceEnvironment, script: 'sfdx force:source:deploy --verbose' + checkOnlyParam + ' --wait 1440 --manifest manifest/package.xml --targetusername ' + salesforceEnvironment
}